# Can't use keyof to assign to a field

Tags: typescript, keyof

I would like some explanation about this error I encounter:

```ts
interface Test {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
function f(obj1: Test, obj2: Test, field: keyof Test) {
    obj1[field] = obj2[field]; // Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Here are some ways I found to circumvent that error:

- if Test contains only numbers or only strings
- if I use `obj1[field as string] = obj2[field]`
- if I change my method to `function f<K extends keyof Test>(obj1: Test, obj2: Test, field: K)`

But I don't understand why this code fails, is it a "bug" in typescript or am I missing something ?

Comment: `function f<T, K extends keyof T>(obj1: T, obj2: T, field: K) {...` Pretty sure it is a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed the 3rd point. Anyway it can't infer they are of the same type because it sees `string | number` on both sides of assignment expression. Once generic type parameter for key is introduced - it can narrow the type according to provided value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because TypeScript doesn't know what type will be returned by `obj2[field]`. It can be either `number` or `string`. In addition, TypeScript doesn't know what type of `obj1[field]` will be. And because it is `number | string` so it decides, for type safety, that it will be `never`, because there are no types that is base for both `number` and `string`. Additionally, TypeScript doesn't know which property name will be in `field`

> if Test contains only numbers or only strings

In that case, TypeScript definitely knows that all fields will be `number` or `string`, so it can infer types for both `obj1[field]` and `obj2[field]`, and it will be the same type.

> if I change my method to function f(obj1: Test, obj2: Test, field: K)

In that case TypeScript knows exactly type for both `obj1[field]` and `obj2[field]`, so it can safely assign value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I guess typescript isn't smart enough to detect both side of the assignment will be the same because field is the same... Still puzzled about my second point (the only one you didn't cite ^^): why casting field as string is not an error anymore, I guess it's the limitation of a type system on top of an untyped language and typescript allows to put everything in an object indexed by a string...

Comment: I did not cite second point because I was not be able to recreate this issue ^^. I guessed that you wrote index signature in `Test` and it could be `[key: string]: number | string`  or even  `[key: string]: any`. But this didn't help me to recreate the issue. If you say more details I will try to help